# How to queue rufus-scheduler jobs

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I have something like the following:

```
# myScript.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

  def loop
    "hey I am i the loop"
  end 

  def run_schedule(url, count, method, interval)
    puts "running scheduler"

    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

    scheduler.every interval do

    loop(url, count, method)
    end
  end  

  run_schedule(url, count, method, interval)
```

My expectation is that when I run:

```
bundle exec ruby myScript.rb url, count, method, interval
```

I see output to STD a bunch of "hey I am in the loop" based on the interval.

What happens is I exit to the command line prompt and never see the loop run.

Comment: I believe that's a typo, you don't need the last `end`. Why do you have the params `url` `count` `method`, if you are not using?

Comment: those are passed in the command line I just didn't explicitly call out the ARGV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you expect

```
def loop
  "hey I am i the loop"
end
```

to output anything to stdout (not STD)? It is just returning a string, it is not calling `print` or `puts`...

```
# myScript.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

def _loop(u, c, m)
  # "loop" is a bad name, it's a Ruby keyword, so using "_loop" instead
  # it's still a bad name

  p "hey I am i the loop"
  p [ Time.now, [ u, c, m ] ]
    # without p or puts nothing gets to stdout
end

$scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
  # creating a single scheduler for the whole script
  # not creating a new scheduler each time run_schedule is called

def run_schedule(url, count, method, interval)

  #puts "running scheduler"
  #scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
    # commenting out...

  $scheduler.every interval do

    _loop(url, count, method)
  end
end

#run_schedule(url, count, method, interval)
run_schedule('url', 'count', 'method', '3s')

$scheduler.join
  # let the Ruby main thread join the scheduler thread so that
  # the Ruby process does not exit and so scheduling may happen
```

and so it goes:

```
"hey I am i the loop"
[2017-02-08 06:06:01 +0900, ["url", "count", "method"]]
"hey I am i the loop"
[2017-02-08 06:06:05 +0900, ["url", "count", "method"]]
"hey I am i the loop"
[2017-02-08 06:06:08 +0900, ["url", "count", "method"]]
```

Note the `$scheduler.join` at the end of the script. That prevents the Ruby process from exiting. Since that process doesn't exist, the threads in it (in our case, the thread in the rufus-scheduler instance) live and do their work. Your initial script was simply exiting, freeing all its resources, as expected.

Comment: oh yes you are right my actual script uses puts, but rewriting the abstraction I excluded it...but you hit the main issue which is the $schedule.join......

Comment: so I think you solved my problem let me give it a go!

Comment: Yes!  this is working, thank you.  I wish this had been in the examples or documentation somehow.  I wouldn't have known to use the $schedule and `join`.....how did you figure that out based on the documentation?

Comment: The join is in the documentation: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler (quickstart.rb top first code example) There is also https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#schedulerjoin and, as a programmer, you should understand that when a program exits, its threads die with it. I wrote rufus-scheduler so I know its documentation. "join" simply follows the Thread#join pattern for programmer familiarity. So please read the documentation before complaining "I wish this had been in the doc". Do not put the blame on others.